# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xgboost’

Tags: rstudio, xgboost

I keep getting this error even though I've already installed the `xgboost` package. I tried the following code and it keep saying the same when I run  `library(xgboost)`. Anyone has any idea?

I've already tried this code and it keep saying the same thing:

```
remove.packages("xgboost")

install.packages('xgboost', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the full text of the error message you are seeing?

Comment: > library(xgboost)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘chron’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘xgboost’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xgboost’

Comment: `no package called ‘chron’` -- this implies you need to install the `chron` package; e.g. with `install.packages("chron")`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin!!!! It worked!